# Close VS Code from terminal

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

I know you can open by doing a 
`code .`
but is there a way to close it with some command?

I found this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/919185/how-do-i-close-a-program-from-the-terminal

but have the same problem mentioned in the comments. I want it to close gracefully and ask to save changes etc..

Comment: If you plan to interact with the window (to save changes, for example) why do you want to start the process from the terminal?

Comment: It's a workflow thing. I usually switch between projects by writing in terminal ```code ../my-other-project``` but the window stays open. So I would like to do something like ```code ../my-other-project && code [close]```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for a more convenient way to close your vscode session you can always use the short-cuts build-in on vscode.
[shortcut image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zloSE.png)

try the shortcuts

> Ctrl + K S to save all

> Ctrl + F4 to close the window